# rpm subpackage %files section

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I want to copy same files to multiple subpackages.Is it really needed to write redundant code to copy files.
Like:

%files sub_pkg1

/a/b/c

/d/e/f

%files sub_pkg2

/a/b/c

/d/e/f

or can i do something like

%files sub_pkg1 sub_pkg2.

i am trying to store subpackages in a list and then iterating a loop but that too is not working:

distros=${distros:-sub_pkg1 aub_pkg2}"

for distro in $distros
do 
%files $distro

/a/b/c

/d/e/f

done

But this is failing with error:
error:  Package does not exist: %files ${distro}

Answer (score 2):

You can use a identical file manifest for 2 different subpackages.

See %files -f manifest, generate the manifest in the %install section:

```
%install
echo /a/b/c > file_list
echo /d/e/f >> file_list

%files sub_pkg1 -f file_list

%files sub_pkg2 -f file_list
```